# Hide/show item inside SXA Accordion component

Tags: sxa

We would like to hide an Accordion item inside an Accordion component programmatically.

For example :

1. Drag and drop Accordion component from SXA toolbox

[image]

2. After adding it, we add new accordion by clicking on (+) sign.

[image]

3. It shows like below :

[image]

Would like to hide "Accordion Item 1" programmatically based on some condition.

Using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to hide it for visitors or editors? And why not just delete it if you don't want it?

Comment: Implementing some functionality for that we need to hide and show accordion item based on condition. Is this possible through code to hide / show accordion item? We can not delete it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this with the existing accordion. Luckily SXA is build very modular so you can do this with a custom version.

You need to create your own version of the accordion - create a copy of the rendering using the existing templates and view but you do need a custom controller.

For that controller, inherit `Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.Controllers.AccordionController`.

You'll need a constructor like `AccordionController(IAccordionRepository accordionRepository)` and your main logic should go into an override of the GetModel. You could call the (ootb) base version first to have your model filled:

```
protected override object GetModel()
{
    var model = base.GetModel();
    ...
}
```

After the model has been filled, you can remove what is needed based on your custom requirements. You will find the composite items in `Model.CompositeItems`.